# Find quantile $p=5/16$ of Poisson distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

Find quantile $p=\frac{5}{16}$ of a Poisson distribution when $\lambda=1$. How do I solve that? I know that the quartile we are looking for is equal to $0$, but how would I find it?

Comment: quartile or percentile?

Comment: I think the word here is _quantile_ (_n_ rather than _r_), which can represent any fraction of the sample space; in this case, $5/16$ is neither a whole multiple of $1/4$ (quartile) nor a whole multiple of $1/100$ (percentile).

Comment: @DavidK Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: A good first step is to write out the definition of "quantile" that you were given. (Not all people define it the same way.) Then look at the Poisson with $\lambda=1$ and see what parts of it fit what parts of the definition. If that doesn't answer the question, edit your definition into the question and show what  you tried so someone may be able to give some guidance.

Comment: OP Use Cumulative Probability table for Poisson distribution and check at which number the probability crosses $5/16$. It's simple in this coz $P(Poi(1) = 0) = 0.3679$. So the answer is $0$.

Comment: I am looking for a method without using a table, just the general formula. I s there any other method that is possible to see that?